# (Logic) Formally writing a rational number in logic

Tags: logic

How do I "formally write" a rational number $a_i$ in a logic formula?

For example, I was taught that $x^2$ should be formally written as $F_\times(x_1,x_1)$, $1$ should be formally written as $c_1$, $2$ should be formally written as $F_+(c_1,c_1)$ and so on.

I hope my question isn't too ambiguous.

This is related to my previous question: [How to show that the property of being algebraically closed is reflected by elementary extensions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/372706/how-to-show-that-the-property-of-being-algebraically-closed-is-reflected-by-elem)

The main idea is I want to write out the formula $\phi_n$ [credit to André Nicolas who suggested it] ,
$$\forall w_0\forall w_1\cdots\forall w_n \exists x\left(x^{n+1}+w_nx^n+\cdots+w_0=0\right).$$

and specify that all the $w_i$ are rationals.

---

background information about the underlying question

If $p(x)=x^{n+1}+a_nx^n+\cdots+a_1x+a_0$ is a polynomial such that $\{a_0,\cdots,a_n\}\subset\mathbb{Q}$, then $p(x)=0$ has a solution in $F$.

Assume that the structure $(F,0,1,+,\cdot)$ is a countable elementary submodel of the complex field $(\mathbb{C},0,1,+,\cdot)$.

---

Sincere thanks for any help!

Comment: A rational number is the quotient of two integers, with the denominator non-zero, so you can require that such integers exist.

Comment: Any **particular** rational number, and therefore any fixed $n$-tuple of rationals, can be captured by a formula. So if you care to, you can add for every specific polynomial with rational coefficients, the assertion it has a root. We cannot, however, **quantify** over the rationals without changing the language. Anyway, we don't need the rationals, integers will do. Any specific integer is easy to express.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can describe any *specific* rational by a formula. Let us find, for example, a formula $\psi_{2/3}(x)$ that "says" that $x=2/3$.

We use the notation implicit in your post.
A formula $\psi_{2/3}(x)$ that does the job is:
$$F_{\times}(F_+(F_+(c_1,c_1),c_1),x)=F_+(c_1,c_1).$$
Any rational number can be specified in this way. The negative ones require an additional trick.

Thus for any **specific** polynomial $P(x)$ with rational coefficients, we can write a sentence that says that this particular polynomial has a zero. And if we want to specify that **every** non-constant polynomial with rational coefficients has a zero, we can do so using a countably infinite set of axioms.

However, we do not really *need* the predicates that identify the specific rationals. For if $P(x)$ is a polynomial with rational coefficients, then $P(x)$ has a zero if and only if a certain  polynomial $P^\ast(x)$ has a zero, where $P^\ast$ is obtained from $P$ by multiplying by a suitable integer, a common denominator of the coefficients of $P$.

And we do not need negative integers. For the polynomial $P(x)$ has a zero if and only if the equation $P_{+}(x)=P_{-}(x)$ has a solution, where $P_{+}$ is the polynomial whose coefficients are the positive coefficients of $P$, and $P_{-}$ is the polynomial whose coefficients are the absolute values of the negative coefficients of $P$.

**Remark:** As explained in the answer of Rob Arthan, introducing a new predicate symbol that says "I am rational" or "I am natural" has undesirable consequences, for decidability, and also for the model theory.

Comment: Thanks, this is an awesomely clear answer.

Comment: You are welcome: clarity is what one seeks.

Comment: thanks, I think the key idea "multiplying by a suitable integer, a common denominator of the coefficients of P ." is really useful. This way one can avoid rationals altogether.

Comment: You are right that one can avoid individual non-intergral rationals, but it is useful to accumulate defining tricks. From my point of view, the main goal there is so that after a while, one "knows" that something complicated *could* be defined, so one needn't bother. A similar thing happens with recursiveness. One proves in gruesome detail that certain basic functions are recursive. After that, for functions that it is clear we *could* prove recursive, details can be left out.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to quantify over the coefficients to solve your original problem [How to show that the property of being algebraically closed is reflected by elementary extensions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/372706/how-to-show-that-the-property-of-being-algebraically-closed-is-reflected-by-elem) (as I have explained there).

The first-order theory of algebraically closed fields of a given characteristic is decidable. In the characteristic $0$ case, adding a predicate for the rational numbers results in an undecidable theory, so it is not a good way to go for your original problem.